# How can I get the text from a javafx TextField added at runtime?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have two buttons in the scene, one triggers the method `newFields()` which makes two new `TextField` inside an `HBox` and the other through the `getText()` method, I would like it to get the typed texts.

sample.fxml:

```
  <VBox prefHeight="275.0" prefWidth="300.0" fx:id="pane">
     <children>
        <Button layoutX="6.0" layoutY="14.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#newFields" text="New Fields" />
        <Button layoutX="6.0" layoutY="53.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#getTexts" text="Get Texts" />
     </children>
  </VBox>
```

Controller.java:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML VBox pane;    
    @FXML void newFields(){    
        HBox hb = new HBox();
        pane.getChildren().add(hb);

        TextField tf = new TextField();
        tf.setPromptText("Name here");    
        TextField tf2 = new TextField();
        tf2.setPromptText("Age here");

        hb.getChildren().addAll(tf, tf2);
    }    
    @FXML void getTexts(){    
        ObservableList<Node> childsVB = pane.getChildren();
        Node hb = childsVB.get(2);
        hb.getChildren();//Cannot resolve method
    }
}
```

I have the node of the `HBox` containing the `Texfield`s but i´m stuck there, I have tried to get the children of the `HBox` but the IDE throws an error.

I´m a new user here, and I really have searched for a answer but with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Node` doesn't have `getChildren()` method. You should use Casting.
Change :

```
Node hb = childsVB.get(2);
```

to:

```
HBox hb = (HBox)childsVB.get(2);
```

Or use  [Pane class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html#getChildren--):

```
Pane pane = (Pane)childsVB.get(2);
```